# Jenkins for continues testing

Tags: jenkins

I would like to use Jenkins for continues testing. Job scenario should look like: 1. connect to svn, call scripts to check-out repo, build and run test. Test will e.g. check if numbers in some output file are same as in reference file. All scripts are in python. The question is - how to force Jenkins to indicate job as "Fail" when numbers in files are different?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would use Jenkins a little differently. It is possible to do exactly what you want but Jenkins and python can eliminate some work for you.

First, Jenkins has the capability to check out stuff from various version control systems, including Subversion. This is the usual way to use Jenkins. When you set up a job, you tell the address of your version control repository and after that you configure the steps to execute after the files have been checked out.

Second, you should use the python test framework http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html to write your tests. Then you can use e.g. nosetests utility to run the tests. Nosetests can even create test reports in xml format and Jenkins can read the reports and show you which tests failed and why they failed (if the report includes that information.)

But to answer your question: If you exit the build step with non-zero exit code, Jenkins will interpret that to mean the build failed and it will mark that build with a red ball.

Jenkins can mark builds as stable (green), unstable (yellow) and failed (red). If the build step exits with non-zero exit code, the build has failed. If the build step exits with zero, Jenkins can be configured to look for test report files. If the test reports have failed tests, the build will be unstable. If all the tests have passed, the build is stable.

Usually people use the failed (red) to indicate a fatal problem in the test (e.g. failure to install the software that should be tested) and then use test reports to indicate unstable or stable build.